# my activity consist of one activity and many hidden layouts. on different button click respective layouts are set to visible

Tags: android, xml

Now my question is this, is there any way to apply any default animation when each of the layout is set to visible? Instead of appearing all of a sudden, any sliding animation would look sleek.

```
              //to show home page
   homeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            liMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
              //to show .net page
    dotnetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            liDotnet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    });
```

Comment: May be you can try view Flipper to show the layouts

Comment: Why can't you use separate Activitys? How are you changing the layout, show us codez